# What causes Hadoop datanodes to be excluded from operations?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm running K-means jobs on a 2 datanode Hadoop cluster. When the input data grows large enough (1.5GB) I can get the following error:

There are 2 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation and 2 data node(s) are excluded in this operation.

The operation is writing a file as indicated by this message that I also get:
File XXX could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes.

Why would any datanode be excluded from this operation? Is it because they are just way to busy with other work? How would I fix the problem in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the disk space was running out on the datanodes during the K-means job. This is what caused a node to be excluded from file writing. It seemed that there was enough space left, but the nodes are excluded already at 90% disk space usage.

Short answer: Lack of disk space can exclude nodes from file write operations.

Answer (score 0):

Share my experience as a reference.

```
Failed to place enough replicas, still in need of 1 to reach 2 (unavailableStorages=[DISK]

org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology: Node 172.22.8.68:50010 is excluded, continuing.
```

A whole rack of nodes may be excluded due to the hdfs blockmanagement policy.